# Installation of cvxopt on MAC 10.11

Tags: macos, installation, cvxopt

Before trying to install cvxopt, Xcode and the Command Line Tools for Xcode were installed.  In addition, Python 2.7.11 was installed.

The installation instruction for cvxopt is:

```
python setup.py install
```

To test if the installation was successful the installation instruction suggests trying an example; namely,

```
cd examples/doc/chap8
python lp.py
```

Unfortunately, the example did not work as shown below.

```
cB_9% python lp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cvxopt import matrix, solvers  
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/cvxopt/__init__.py", line 255, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/cvxopt/lapack.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/cvxopt/lapack.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/brucesmi/.python-eggs/cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/cvxopt/lapack.so, 2): Symbol not found: _dgesv_
  Referenced from: /Users/brucesmi/.python-eggs/cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/cvxopt/lapack.so
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
 in /Users/brucesmi/.python-eggs/cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/cvxopt/lapack.so
```

To try to figure out what the problem is, I gave the command:

```
cB_10% ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
```

which returned

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
```

So, I do not have any idea how to correct this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How, and where, did you install Python? If you run `which python` does it show that it is using the Apple-provided Python or the one you installed? You need to be specific about how you start Python and which one you want.

Comment: Mark: Thanks for your comment. "which python" returns the one I installed.

Comment: Installed atlas now

BLAS_LIB_DIR = '/usr/local/lib'

BLAS_LIB = ['f77blas','cblas','atlas','fortran']  
command import cvxopt results in:
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/smith/.python-eggs/cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/cvxopt/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: __gfortran_st_write
  Referenced from: /Users/smith/.python-eggs/cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/cvxopt/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

Installed gcc-5, I believe that fortran are available and in the right folder; namely,
/usr/local/lib